# how to create a conditional root route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a nice way of creating a dynamic root route that is decided by the host.

for example

```
if host == "www.site1.com"
   root :to => "customers#new"
elsif == "www.site2.com"
   root :to => "another_controller#action"
end
```

one of the issues i get is when i try to request host in routes.rb i return an error 
"undefined local variable or method `request".

i plan on having a configuration file that will determine which host gets which root.

is this possible?

thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (Delta the incorrect usage of `elsif` here.)

Comment: one of the first issues i hit appears to be "undefined local variable or method `request' "  when i try to request what the host is in routes.  i tried to add this to my initial question but i can't seem to edit.

Comment: Oh, no, you can't query the request in routes, and that doesn't make any sense. You can do that in an action and render, redirect, etc. but I'm not convinced that's the best way to do it.